# Can turning Deliverability on cause previously triggered emails to be sent?

Tags: email, email-alert, queue, deliverability

**The Scenario:**

1. I turn deliverability off in my salesforce org
2. I update records which trigger automation to send out email alerts. No emails are sent because deliverability is turned off
3. I turn deliverability back on

**My question:** Will the email alerts be held in a queue and sent out when deliverability is turned back on in step 3? Or does the automation have to be re-triggered to send out those email alerts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the email alerts be held in a queue and sent out when deliverability is turned back on in step 3?

No. Anything you "send" while deliverability is disabled will never be sent. Note that this only applies to emails that were actually sent. For example, let's say you add a time delay of one hour on the email send, you update a bunch of records, then enable deliverability. As long as it's enabled before the timed delay kicks off, the emails would then send. The system checks at the time the email is added to the email queue.